# "No such file or directory" in hadoop while executing WordCount program using jar command

Tags: hadoop, jar, word-count

I am new to Hadoop and am trying to execute the WordCount Problem.

*Things I did so far -*

Setting up the Hadoop Single Node cluster referring the below link.
http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php

Write the word count problem referring the below link
https://kishorer.in/2014/10/22/running-a-wordcount-mapreduce-example-in-hadoop-2-4-1-single-node-cluster-in-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit/

Problem is when I execute the last line to run the program -

hadoop jar wordcount.jar /usr/local/hadoop/input /usr/local/hadoop/output

Following is the error I get -
[image]
The directory seems to be present
[image]
The file is also present in the directory with contents
[image]

Finally, on a side note I also tried the following directory sturcture in the jar command.
[image]

No avail! :/

I would really appreciate if someone could guide me here!

Regards,
Paul Alwin

Comment: Did you checked if jar file is in right path? Didn't you mistaken your local path with path on virtual machine?

Comment: @Luk - The jar seems to be at the right path, I also tried wrong a wrong path intentionally and it gives me another error something like 'jar not found' or something. I am wondering, if this says 'File directory' not found has to do something with File not being in place or something. ahh!

Comment: @Luk - _Just clearing my understanding here_ -

The Linux machine is installed as a virtual box on my windows - The Hadoop is installed there.
The jar is in the folder specified in the image above and the input file is supposed to be in the Hdfs folder created.
And the output will again be generated in a Hdfs folder as specified in the command ( will be generated - need not be created prior)
This is my understanding of how this works, feel free to correct!

Answer (score 1):

Your first image is using input from the local Hadoop installation directory, /usr

If you want to use that data on your local filesystem, you can specify `file:///usr/...`

Otherwise, if you're running pseudo distributed mode, HDFS has been setup, and `/usr` does not exist in  HDFS unless you explicitly created it there.

Based on the stacktrace, I believe the error comes from the `/app/hadoop/` staging directory path not existing, or the permissions for it are not allowing your current user to run commands against that path

Suggestion: Hortonworks and Cloudera offer pre-built VirtualBox images and lots of tutorial resources. Most companies will have Hadoop from one of those vendors, so it's better to get familiar with that rather than mess around with having to install Hadoop yourself from scratch, in my opinion

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
Yes, the first image uses the input from the local directory, although in the last image I am using the input from the hdfs directory I made. 
I did not seem to make a difference. 

I am not sure what a pseudo-distributed mode is, but the user _hduser_ is something I created while going through the tutorial I mentioned. 

Also, yes I does look like there could be some permissions issue here, alhough I am not sure where, maybe on the file in the HDFS.

And thanks for your suggestion, I would like to try more to get this fixed else I would try HortonWorks :)

Comment: although feel free to ask me to show any more information regarding this!

Comment: Pseudo distributed means that Hadoop is configured in cluster mode, but only on a single machine... In the core-site.xml, you set the fs.defaultFS to start with `hdfs://`? Otherwise, if it started with `file://`, your error wouldn't likely happen. Can you please show output of `ls -l /app` to the question?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a configuration issue somewhere. And the stacktrace explicitly says that file permissions are being checked on both errors. You'll need to add your Hadoop XML files to the question

Comment: This is my conre-site.xml 


 <property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
 </property>

Seems to start with hdfs! Is it a problem, should i change to file://?

Comment: You can, but then you're just running a single Java mapreduce process locally, and not even using Hadoop for what it's meant for

Comment: OK also following is the output

/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.0/bin$ ls -l /app
total 0

"total 0" is the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166720/discussion-between-paul-alwin-and-cricket-007).

Comment: There should be a folder there. Go over the first link you posted again and make sure you get through `sudo mkdir -p /app/hadoop/tmp`.